# Bind datatable to listview wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, listview

I've tried almost all the soulutions provided on stackoverflow and can't seem to get it to work. Am new to wpf and mvvm and was trying to bind a datatable to a listview and below is my code.

```
//code for viewmodel
public DataTable RetrieveDetails
        {

            get
            {
                DataTable users = new DataTable();
                string dataBaseName = "name.db3";
                using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dataBaseName + "; Version=3;"))
                {                    
                    var details = "SELECT * FROM users";                    
                    connection.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(details, connection);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(details, connection);
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                    return ds.Tables[0];

                }
            }

        }
```

And below is how i bind the datatable to my list view

```
<ListView x:Name="FormOneView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RetrieveDetails}">
                            <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" />
                            </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

I know this is supposed to be simple but am having a hard time displaying the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<ListView x:Name="FormOneView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding Path=allData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="243,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Time" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tid}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Acceleration" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Acceleration}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

in this XAML I'm giving you an example of a datatable with two columns. I'm binding my ListView columns to my sql table column headers using DisplayMemberBinding.

Your backgournd code is actually fine, but you need to bind the DataContext of your ListView using propertyChangedEventHandler. Below is an example of how to do such a binding:

Add following two lines in your method:

```
adapter.Fill(ds, "users");
allData = ds.Tables["users"].DefaultView;
```

Then add following methods in your class. Your class should inherit INotifyPeropertyChanged
(yourClassName : INotifyPeropertyChanged) otherwise it won't work.

```
private DataView _allData;
public DataView allData
{
    get { return _allData; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _allData)
        {
            _allData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("allData");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in order for the above code to work, need to add the following line of code
listview.datacontext = class holding alldata.allData

Comment: The code example includes a DataTable. They need to be set DataContext property on the FormOneView ListView. Maybe the code example could show this more precisely.